# Mail sending through java got 550 parameter error

Tags: java, email

I have a requirement to send mails through java. Here I am getting error as "550 Parameter required for helo or set g_helo_optional true". Not able to identify this error. kindly help me in this.

Comment: As it said, the remote server doesn't know for the HELO command, so by setting the g_helo_optional to true you can avoid sending the command (it becomes optional). Was is working on that server before?

Comment: How exactly are you sending the mails? Please provide some of your code so we can get the idea of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send your host name after the `HELO` command.